# Memcache build error on CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, memcached, centos7

I have a problem installing "Pterodactyl Panel" on Centos 7. I am stuck at the line "pecl install memcache". The errors are shown below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# pecl install memcache
WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
downloading memcache-2.2.7.tgz ...
Starting to download memcache-2.2.7.tgz (36,459 bytes)
..........done: 36,459 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
Enable memcache session handler support? [yes] : y
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootEloe5R/memcache-2.2.7
running: /var/tmp/memcache/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --enable-memcache-session=y
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... no
checking for gcc... no
configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-rootEloe5R/memcache-2.2.7':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/var/tmp/memcache/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --enable-memcache-session=y' failed
[root@localhost ~]# configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-rootEloe5R/memcache-2.2.7'
```

This is a newly-formatted VPS with Centos 7. I started from the beginning of the tutorial to install the "Pterodactyl Panel".

These are the commands I executed before getting to this point:

```
yum install -y epel-release https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm

yum update -y

yum install -y httpd openssl-devel php71u php71u-common php71u-fpm php71u-cli php71u-json php71u-mysqlnd php71u-mcrypt php71u-gd php71u-mbstring php71u-pdo php71u-zip php71u-bcmath php71u-dom php71u-opcache php71u-devel pecl php71u-devel pecl pear1u memcached

# Enable Memcached
systemctl enable memcached
systemctl start memcached

# Install PHP Module
pecl install memcache
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error

```
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

You don't have a compiler installed

```
yum install gcc
```